# Javascript Constants in ES6

Tags: javascript, es6

What would be the preferred way to create constants in javascript, specifically with ES6?

Currently I have a constants class which has methods that return the string I'm looking for.

```
 class Constants {
    constructor() {}

    SOMECONSTANT() {
       return 'someconstant';
    }
 }
```

Comment: see [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backwards compatibility, I would create a read-only property of the encapsulating object, which could be the global object:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'CONST', {
  value: 123,
  writable: false
});
```

See: [Object.defineProperty - `writable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Writable_attribute)

Otherwise, ES6 has a `const` keyword.

```
const name1 = value1 [, name2 = value2 [, ... [, nameN = valueN]]];
```

See [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Comment: My understanding with the const keyword is that it can only be used in local scope.  I should have clarified I need the constants scoped globally.

Comment: Local or global. It's block scoped, I think.